# Setting Thread.CurrentPrincipal in MVC Application so that it can be used in service layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, authorization

I am confused as to whether or not it is safe to set the Thread.CurrentPrincipal equal to the signed in user in an MVC application i.e. so that I can perform authorization checks in my service layer?

This stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085560/authorization-user-info-in-a-service-layer-net-application) recommends doing this.... but in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543908/obtaining-the-current-principal-outside-of-the-web-tier) the author suggests that there are issues with setting Thread.CurrentPrincipal. What exactly are these issues?

Also would I need to set the Thread.CurrentPrincipal for every request made by a logged in user?

Comment: What kind of authentiaction are you using?

Comment: Forms based authentication using asp.net identity. Also using external providers e.g. facebook.

Comment: I think the first question is kind of subjective. Personally, I see no problem in use CurrentPrincipal in the service layer. Are Thread.CurrentPrincipal null in your debug? The ASP .NET Identity should already set it for you, if I'm not wrong.